# Understanding the Node 'link' in the Node Class

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

So in the Node Class one of the Node objects attributes is `link` which itself a Node. Is the `link` Node an object itself in a way? To truly explain my question let’s say we have a LinkedList with:

`temp1` being the 1st Node in the list and `temp2` being the 2nd Node in the list.

In reality, `temp1` and `temp2` are just reference variables to the real objects in the heap. So when I do `temp1.link` (`temp1.link = temp2`), does that mean `temp1.link` as an entirety equal `temp2` or does that mean just the `.link` portion of `temp1.link` equal `temp2`?

I am confused because since `link` is a Node does that mean it is a reference variable to an object on its own? Can an object have an attribute that is also the same datatype (like self-referential)?

Does the `link` pointer, point to `temp2` objects address in memory heap. Or does the `link` pointer point to the object reference variable `temp2` FIRST and then 'temp2' points to the object address in memory and returns it up the line to `link`?

What *started* this question in the first place was:
What does `newTreeNode.compareTo(current)//TreeNode current = root` do compared to `newTreeNode.data.compareTo(current.data)` because doesn’t only the object reference variable `newTreeNode` have access to using the `compareTo()` method and not `newTreeNode.data`?

Comment: `link` is a reference to a `Node` instance on the heap, exactly as `temp2` is.

Comment: Seems to me like you are struggling with the idea of pointers. Yes, references are pointers into the heap.  All objects are on the heap from the moment you create them (even the reference to `this` is a pointer into the heap). Yes, objects can have cyclical references (self-referential references are fine). When an object has a field with an object of any type, it is always a pointer so there are no issues caused by self-referential types. To learn more about how the Oracle JVM does references, you might find this interesting(or slightly confusing): https://stackoverflow.com/q/58387338/5987669

Comment: If you use backticks(\`) instead of single quotes('), you can make code blocks in your question. It is normally the same button as ~, but I don't know it is available on all mobile devices.

Comment: @Locke Thank you for the link, that was super interesting, and exactly the type of stuff I'm into!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the `link` Node an object itself in a way?

It points to a `Node` the same way `temp1` or `temp2` does. There is not really a concept of ownership though. `link` is not a node, but it can tell you where to find one. You can think of `link` as just an index in memory. It links that node to the next one by acting as a pointer to the next node in the chain. `link` could be `null`, the same `Node` (although that would not make much sense for a linked list), or a different `Node`.

> SO when I do `temp1.link = temp2` does that mean `temp1.link` as an entirety equal `temp2` or does that mean just the `.link` portion of `temp1.link` equal temp2?

It means that `temp1.link` is the same pointer as `temp2`. Conceptually you only ever work with references in Java since you can't actually allocate an object on the stack.

```java
public class Node {
    int value;
    Node link;
}


// a and b point to the data of each node
Node a = new Node();
Node b = new Node();

// Give some data
a.value = 2;
b.value = 9;

// Now a contains a pointer to the data of b.
a.link = b;

// We can check this by printing the value of the linked node
System.out.println(a.value); // 2
System.out.println(a.link.value); // 9

// We can also have an object store a pointer to itself
b.link = b;

// We can check this by printing the value of the linked node
System.out.println(b.link.value);

// We can also check b and b.link are the same pointers.
System.out.println(b == b.link); // true
```

> I am confused because since `link` is a Node does that mean it is a reference variable to an object on its own? Can an object have an attribute that is also the same datatype(like self-referential)?

Don't think of `link` as a `Node`. `link` is just a pointer to something of type `Node`. Because it is just a pointer, it can be self-referential.

> Does the `link` pointer, point to `temp2` objects address in memory heap. Or does the `link` pointer point to the object reference variable `temp2` FIRST and then `temp2` points to the object address in memory and returns it up the line to `link`?

Both `link` and `temp2` point to the data in the heap for the same `Node`. Pointers are just integers so `link` and `temp2` are completely indistinguishable in memory. Java does not let you use raw pointers so it is not possible to take a pointer to a variable on the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much Locke! This helped a lot, not just understanding pointers, but their place in the JVM. Also incase you have to explain this to anyone else, saying that the pointers are just integers, and they are indistinguishable in memory, helped a ton to recognize: that the pointers `temp1.link` and `temp2` arnt addresses to a house themselves, but more like different real estate agents, that show you the same house address to reach the same house.